# Native component for "RCTFBLikeView" does not exist

Tags: ios, react-native, fbsdk, react-native-fbsdk

I am currently trying to set up the FBSDK for react-native (react-native-fbsdk).
It was working great in previous versions when I was running react-native-fbsdk@0.1.0 and react-native@0.41.0.
However, right now with react-native-fbsdk@0.6.0 and react-native@0.45.1, I had to reinstall a lot of components.

My app is sending me:

`Warning: Native component for "RCTFBLikeView" does not exist
Warning: Native component for "RCTFBLoginButton" does not exist
Warning: Native component for "RCTFBSendButton" does not exist
Warning: Native component for "RCTFBShareButton" does not exist`

So considering to other posts like this, this is supposed to be due to a problem with libRCTFBSDK.a.

However, after removing and adding back this file from *Build Phases*, the problem is still occuring.

Is there a way to find the latest version of this file somewhere? I do not see it in the *node_modules* and I am only adding it from *workspace*.

Comment: If you go into xCode, click your project, then click the name of your project in the targets section and make sure that libRCTFBSDK.a is in the `Linked Frameworks and Libraries`

Comment: @GarrettMcCullough I'm having this same issue and libRCTFBSDK.a just isn't there to be added. I believe this is a new issue, it doesn't seem to get linked correctly.

Comment: It could be a new issue.  I'm on an older version (v.4?) and I had to manually install things because linking didn't work then

Comment: Yes I tried removing and adding back libRCTFbsdk.a but it did not work :/